# While reindexing a Series , values are changing into NaN's

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
n = np.arange(0,5)
s = Series(n,index =['a','b','c','d','e'])
print(s)
s= s.reindex(['A','B','C','D','E'])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
dtype: int64
A   NaN
B   NaN
C   NaN
D   NaN
E   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Answer (score 3):

Use the script below. It will change the value of the index to your desired values. Reindex will not change the values but will change the order of the records and if such index value is not found, it will put NaN.

OLD:

```
s= s.reindex(['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

New:

```
s.index=['A','B','C','D','E']
```

Result:

```
A    0
B    1
C    2
D    3
E    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You need to accept the answer if its helps you to resolve your issue.. thats how stackoverflow works. refer : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work